# sudo apt upgrade fails

Tags: ubuntu, apt, upgrade

`sudo apt upgrade` fails, returning the following error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6 : Breaks: fakeroot (< 1.25.3-1.1ubuntu2~)
         Breaks: fakeroot:i386 (< 1.25.3-1.1ubuntu2~)
         Recommends: libnss-nis but it is not installable
         Recommends: libnss-nisplus but it is not installable
E: Broken packages
```

Comment: Have you first prepared the package cache with `apt update`?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?